# Shared drive - unable to see from my Elementary OS computer

Tags: samba

I have two computers - one with Linux Mint 18.2 (Sonya), and one with Elementary OS 0.4.1 (Loki).  The Mint computer has a shared hard drive, and it has Samba installed to make the drive shareable on the network.  When I installed Elementary OS a couple of weeks ago, I was able to access the shared drive by clicking on "Entire Network" in file manager.  I then saw the Mint computer, clicked on it, and saw the shared folder.  I then had full access to the shared folder from my Elementary OS computer.  I have continued to have access till a couple of days ago, when we had a power failure at the house.  When the power came back on, my Elementary OS could see the Mint computer, but could no longer see the shared folder: "Unable to Mount Folder -- Could not connect to the server for this folder.  Failed to mount Windows share; No such file or directory".

Is there perhaps a file or two that got corrupted when the power went off and the computer went off at that point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran all updates from the Terminal window, rebooted, and now I can access the shared drive.  Perhaps something had gotten stepped on, and an update fixed it.

Comment: Which updates did you install to solve the problem of not seeing the shared folders within the option ‘entire network’, cause I have the same problem after installing and configure Samba. Unable to Mount Folder -- Could not connect to the server for this folder. Failed to mount Windows share; No such file or directory". I’m busy with finding a solution for that problem, because last week everything worked good.